# Sort through microsecond data and save day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, datetime

I would like some help figuring out how many days in a month something happened.
This dataset is 30 years of microsecond occurrences (if an event is triggered, the data is recorded)

What Im trying to do is see how often an event happens in X days per month.

```
DataFrame
                  datetime  year  month  day  hour      lon     lat         diy
0      1989-01-07 02:21:55  1989      1    7     2 -122.201  47.577  1989-01-07
1      1989-01-07 02:24:30  1989      1    7     2 -122.190  47.555  1989-01-07
2      1989-01-07 02:24:32  1989      1    7     2 -122.437  47.585  1989-01-07
3      1989-02-17 21:53:13  1989      2   17    21 -120.844  47.438  1989-02-17
4      1989-02-17 21:53:33  1989      2   17    21 -120.844  47.438  1989-02-17
...                    ...   ...    ...  ...   ...      ...     ...         ...
212978 2019-12-14 00:10:41  2019     12   14     0 -124.880  48.605  2019-12-14
212979 2019-12-19 14:38:32  2019     12   19    14 -125.244  48.493  2019-12-19
212980 2019-12-19 14:49:23  2019     12   19    14 -125.200  48.543  2019-12-19
212981 2019-12-19 14:52:09  2019     12   19    14 -125.203  48.551  2019-12-19
212982 2019-12-31 21:00:11  2019     12   31    21 -124.155  47.684  2019-12-31
```

So we can see on Jan 7,1989 3 events happened. Would like to separate to just days
In plain English, in the month of January there was 1 day that data was recorded.I'm not worried about how many events happened in that one day. Just want to focus on how many days in that month had an event.

```
  # What I Want: NewDataFrame
      datetime  days_with_occurrences
0      1989-01                      1
1      1989-02                      1
2      1989-03                      3
```

I've tried using df.grouby
x = df.groupby('datetime').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'days_with_occurrences'})

but this is giving me the total counts...

```
        datetime  days_with_occurrences
0     1989-01-07                      3
1     1989-02-17                      2
2     1989-03-07                      3
3     1989-03-10                      1
4     1989-03-13                      2
```

Comment: do you mean `df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(len)` ?

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been tweaking this and almost have something.

Comment: glad it is useful. What is missing still?